# How to connect multiple clients in Flask using socket.io?

Tags: python, flask-socketio

I want to get data in my Flask server from a socket.io client. My setting is:

1. Client1 calls method request_data on server.
2. The method request_data then emits 'client2' event on Client2.

I have the following method in my flask server:

```
@socketio.on('client1')
def test_message(message):                    
    emit('client2', {'data': 'testdata'})
```

On the client that should receive the data:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':'+location.port);
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('my event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
    });

    socket.on('client2', function(msg) {
        console.log(msg.data)
        console.log("here")
    });
  });
```

But I cannot seem to establish the connection to client2. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `emit` function without explicitly indicating a recipient, then the event is sent back to the caller, which in your example is the client that sent the `client1` event to the server.

If you want to emit to a different client, you need to know its session id (or `sid`). In any handler, you can use `request.sid` to obtain the session ID of the sender. So for example, you could write a connect handler that records these session IDs attached to your application specific data, and then when you want to send something to a specific client, do something like this:

```
emit('client2', {'data': 'testdata'}, room=get_sid_for_user(username))
```

Here the `room` argument specifies which room to emit the message to. All users have a default room that is named with their session ID.